# How to get the exact location of a user with google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ip-address

So i want to get the pin point location of a user coming to my website. I have used a few services like maxmind etc but they are not exact, it just shows you the city or area but not the pin point location.

The only service that does show my exact location is google, how can i use the api to get the exact location from an ip address. Right now i am using

```
$address = json_decode( file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$lat.','.$lon) );
```

**How do i do the same thing but by just passing in the ip address.**

Comment: It's not possible to get the exact location from an IP.

Comment: i know that we cant be very exact, but still google is able to pinpoint my exact location. They should have an api for public use.

Comment: when google knows your exact location you probably have stored your location in your google-account(but this information is not accessible inside the maps-API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that using the Google Maps Geolocation API. Here is some code that does just that:

```
  function findLatLonFromIP(apiKey) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.ajax({
        url: `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=${apiKey}`,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({considerIp: true}),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data) => {
          if (data && data.location) {
            resolve({lat: data.location.lat, lng: data.location.lng});
          } else {
            reject('No location object in geolocate API response.');
          }
        },
        error: (err) => {
          reject(err);
        },
      });
    });
  }
```

Note that the response from the API also gives you a radius giving you the precision of the IP-based location. The Latitude and Longitude returned is an approximation.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to use the HTML5 Geolocation API, to be more precise the [getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition)-method.

But keep in mind that not all browsers do support this and the user needs to confirm that you are trying to locate him.

Examples can be found e.g. here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: I would say pretty much every browser supports it - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=geolocation). The only perk is that you have to use https on chrome now

Comment: So i guess i cant get the exact location with just PHP. Anyways thanks for confirming this. Here is a great demo of how it might work with html5 https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-use-geolocation-api-with-google-maps